# Magento 1 : each() function is deprecated

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7, deprecated

In Magento 1, I have been getting this error:

> Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /var/www/html/test/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 757

Code:

```
if (is_array($table)) {
    list($tableAlias, $tableName) = each($table);
} else {
    $tableName = $table;
}
```

How to solve this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's too much different question which you duplicated. First of all, please read it :)

Comment: apologies for the inconvenience. +1 for your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace this below code in if condition :

> list($tableAlias, $tableName) = [key($table), current($table)];

As like :

```
if (is_array($table)) {
    list($tableAlias, $tableName) = [key($table), current($table)];
} else {
    $tableName = $table;
}
```