# Magento 2 - php 7.2 - The each() function is deprecated in AbstractCollection.php

Tags: magento-2.1, php-7.2, deprecated

I am getting below error in Magento 2.1 using PHP 7.2.

> main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/ on line 803 in

```
list($tableAlias, $tableName) = each($table);
```

Comment: Replace that line with `list($tableAlias, $tableName) = [key($table), current($table)];` and check it.

Comment: Refer this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Answer Refereed by @RohanHapani

You Should use:

```
list($tableAlias, $tableName) = [key($table), current($table)];
```

Then Code is Like:

```
if (is_array($table)){
    list($tableAlias, $tableName) = [key($table), current($table)];
} else {
    $tableName = $table;
}
```

Hope this may help You!!